# Vector Rotation - Casting a Cone

Tags: unity, c#, quaternion

I'm working on an obstacle avoidance system in unity, and my thought is to cast a sphere along the velocity; if it hits, draw a ring of spheres around that one and repeat until max ring count or a clear path is found.

2D example

[image: 2D circle packing]

To accomplish this, I'm currently rotating the vector up and then rotating again using the velocity as the axis of rotation, and casting a sphere along the new vector.

working example

[image]

This works fine (although I'm not sure how performant it is) until the initial direction is not one of the cardinal directions.

what's happening when things go wrong

[image]

My understanding is that after the following line, rotatedVector would be a vector of equal magnitude to ray, but pointing in a new direction that could be described as having rotated about the velocityDirection a number of degrees equal to the magnitude of velocityDirection.

```
var rotatedVector = Quaternion.Euler(velocityDirection) * ray;
```

But that only seems to be happening when the velocityDirection is aligned with +- World.up, forward, or right.

Any ideas as to what's happening or how I can accomplish this goal?

Code to DrawGizmos

```
public int NumRings = 3;
private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Vector3 velocityDirection = transform.forward * MaxSpeed;
    NumRings = Mathf.Clamp(NumRings, 0, 6);

    Gizmos.color = Color.cyan;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumRings; i++) {
        Vector3 rotationAxis = Vector3.Cross(velocityDirection, velocityDirection + Vector3.up).normalized * Mathf.Atan(i*2/ MaxSpeed) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Vector3 probe;
        if (rotationAxis.magnitude > 0) {
            probe = Quaternion.Euler(rotationAxis) * velocityDirection;
        } else {
            probe = velocityDirection;
        }

        int numProbes = i == 0 ? 1 : 6*i;
        rotationAxis = velocityDirection.normalized;
        for (int j = 0; j < numProbes; j++) {
            var test = Quaternion.Euler(rotationAxis * 360 / numProbes * j) * probe;
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + test);
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position + test, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want AngleAxis, not Euler.

Comment: @DMGregory That was it! thank you so much! If you'd like to add this as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as correct. If anyone else is interested I changed the line var test to {var test = Quaternion.AngleAxis(360 / numProbes * j, rotationAxis) * probe;} which solved the problem.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below. You might also want to edit your question to ask "How do I rotate one vector around another" since your question seems to be about that and not about the collision avoidance part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DMGregory pointed out that the vector rotation function I was looking for was Quaternion.AngleAxis.

Changing var test to the below resulted in the desired behavior.

```
var test = Quaternion.AngleAxis(360 / numProbes * j, rotationAxis) * probe;
```

Thanks again @DMGregory